Convection current in water between 4 degrees and 0 degree Celsius
I would like to understand if convection currents in water at 4-degrees Celsius and below can happen.
Let's say we have container of water, and there is a temperature gradient (or thermal layers) of 0-degree to 4-degrees Celcius.  Water at 0 degrees has the lowest density, compared to water at 4-degrees, having the highest density.
As the lowest density molecules (0-degrees) stay at the top and highest density molecules (4-degrees) stay at the bottom, would convection current between the thermal layers still occur?
Thank you.
